# Branding Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autologin, kiosk-mode, branding

We are trying to customize windows log on process for our product.
We've established Auto-Logon for a user and replacement of the shell.

However, we can't seem to be able to remove the authentication UI.

Changing the following:

1. BrandingNeutral = 1
2. HideAutoLogonUI = 1
3. HideFirstLogonAnimation = 1

caused the whole process be hidden, but since it takes windows some time to log on, the user waits a lot for our shell to start and sees only a blank screen in the meanwhile.

The goal is to show a background of our logo during this time, but only the backgound.

Changing the above values brought us only to the point where the user can see a short authentication (with the username, password and status indicator) which we want to hide.

Attached ([here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/FuXkPDM18VZW4p7z8)) is a clip of what the user sees.
we want to remove the short blue screen and the username display, and replace it with the same logo custom background, in such a way that when windows starts up, the user sees a logo and then the application starts up - no usernames nor passwords.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm currently facing the same issue, i.e. a long period of black screen due to hiding auto logon. Is there not the option to simply show a static image during this time to avoid so much black screen? I'm worried users will not realize that the device is still booting.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution to your requests, but the policies below will help with hiding the username at sign-in and when the session is locked.

Go to `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options` (Run command: `gpedit.msc`).

Turn **on** the following policies:

- `Interactive logon: Don't display username at sign-in`*
- `Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in`

Turn **off** the following policy:

- `Interactive logon: Display user information when the session is locked`

* [Introduced with Windows 10 **1703**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-dont-display-username-at-sign-in)